# In red color or red color of... Which one is better?

Tags: meaning

> These shirts are popular in red color .
>
> Red color of these shirts are popular this year.

Is there any difference between two sentence or both are correct ? I couldn't understand difference  between two of them in meaning.

Comment: Neither is idiomatic English. How about "Red is a popular color for shirts this year"?

Answer (score 3):

In the first example, I would remove the word 'color'.

> These shirts are popular in **red**.

This would be the most common way to say this.

The second example you gave sounds like it is the specific shade of red that is popular, instead of the red shirt. If you want to make sure you are talking about the shirts, do not use '**red color of** these shirts'.

Comment: Agree, "popular in red" sounds best. "In X" is an idiomatic phrasing for limited types of adjectives: _The shirt also comes in black; Do you sell these pants in large?; I've never seen these candies in blue before._